# Multiple Exports From ReactJS Component Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to create a component library with multiple independent components folders. The end goal is to allow a user to do something like

```
import { Header } from 'component-library/theme/one' 
import { Header as HeaderTwo } from 'component-library/theme/two'
```

But when i try to import it, i get this errors:

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5IKn.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcUCP.png)

I have structured folder like:

```
src
 -index.js
themes
 one
   - index.js
 two
   - index.js
```

Comment: Have you checked out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485821/react-module-parse-failed

Comment: @WendyZhang I already tried to config my webpack, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you export your components like `export default` then you can import it with whatever name you want. `import { whatever } from ....`

Comment: but my problem is the way to compile sub-folders, I need to use other components with `import { Header } from 'library/theme/two'`. in this case, I need to use Header from theme two

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it, I changed my package.json with:

```
"main": "./_modules/index.js",
"exports": {
  ".": "./_modules/index.js",
  "./theme_two": "./_modules/themes/two/index.js"
},
```

So, if I want to add more themes, only should add the reference from _modules folder.